# Increment code for test should be '++@count'?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I am beginner of CoffeeScript and Jasmine. At first, I tried to pass test with below code:

```
class Counter
    count: 0

    constructor: ->
        @count = 0

    increment: ->
        @count++

    decrement: ->
        @count--

    reset: ->
        @count = 0

root = exports ? this
root.Counter = Counter
```

The jasmine test code is below:

```
describe("Counter", ->
    counter = new Counter
    it("shold have 0 as a count variable at first", ->
        expect(counter.count).toBe(0)
    )

    describe('increment()', ->
        it("should count up from 0 to 1", ->
            expect(counter.increment()).toBe(1)
        )
    )
)
```

Then kind person told me that the code should be as below:

```
class Counter
    count: 0

    constructor: ->
        @count = 0

    increment: ->
        ++@count

    decrement: ->
        --@count

    reset: ->
        @count = 0

root = exports ? this
root.Counter = Counter
```

Yes, this code passed the test. But I have a question that the former code is more natural than latter code. I have no idea how to certain this question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean "more natural"? If you've only seen a postincrement, then a preincrement may seem foreign, but it's just as valid.

Comment: New related to your question, but that `counter = new Counter` should be wrapped in a `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change your code to the following to be more clear about return values if you choose to stick to post increment

```
class Counter
  count: 0

  constructor: ->
    @count = 0

  increment: ->
    @count++
    @count

  decrement: ->
    @count--
    @count
  reset: ->
    @count = 0

root = exports ? this
root.Counter = Counter
```

or you could change your test to:

```
describe('increment()', ->
  it("should count up from 0 to 1", ->
    expect(counter.count).toBe(0)
    counter.increment()
    expect(counter.count).toBe(1)
  )
)
```

but then you don't expect the returned value of increment and decrement to reflect the updated value of @count

here's an example to play with that will make the differences obvious:
http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Counter%0A%20%20count%3A%200%0A%0A%20%20increment%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40count%2B%2B%0A%20%20%20%20%40count%0A%20%20%0A%20%20inc%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40count%2B%2B%0A%0A%20%20decrement%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20--%40count%0A%0A%20%20dec%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40count--%0A%0Acnt%20%3D%20new%20Counter%0Aalert%20cnt.increment()%0Aalert%20cnt.count%0Aalert%20cnt.inc()%0Aalert%20cnt.count%0Aalert%20cnt.decrement()%0Aalert%20cnt.count%0Aalert%20cnt.dec()%0Aalert%20cnt.count

Answer (score 2):

That's the basic difference between pre and post increment. `@count++` will return the value of `@count` and increment it afterwards. `++@count` will increment it first and return the new value. That's the reason your test fails if you use `@count++`. More about [increment and decrement operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).